# Powershell - Checking variable for value in foreach - If no value then log other output

Tags: powershell

I'm having issue with my foreach method. I am checking in the registry whether a good amount of programs are installed. How would I write it to say something is not installed one time versus it saying something's not installed for each key it checks? Now, If I place a ElseIf it executes "PowerBroker not installed." about 16 times. This is due to it checking every key and writing it out for each key it does not find a match to the displayname. How do I go about it checking the key and only writing it out one time if it's not installed?? Thanks!

```
$UninstallKeys = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
foreach($Key in $UninstallKeys){

if($Key.GetValue("DisplayName") -Match "BeyondTrust"){

    $PBW = $Key.GetValue("DisplayName")
    $PBWV = $Key.GetValue("DisplayVersion")


        if ($PBW) {

            $PBW = $PBW, $PBWV

        }
        else {

            $PBW = "PowerBroker not installed."
            $installsmissing = "True"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this script a whirl. If I've understood the requirement correctly it should give you what you need.

```
$displayName = "BeyondTrust"

$uninstallKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

# Filter the keys down by their display name property
$specificUninstallKeys = $uninstallKeys |
    Where-Object {
        $_.GetValue("DisplayName") -eq $displayName
    }

# Did we find any keys of that name?
if ($specificUninstallKeys) {
    Write-Output "Keys found: $($specificUninstallKeys.Length)"
}
else {
    Write-Output "Sorry pal, no keys by that name here!"
}

# There may be more than one; hence the loop-y requirement here.
foreach ($specificUninstallKey in $specificUninstallKey) {
    Write-Output $displayName
    Write-Output $specificUninstallKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and let you know shortly. I need to update about 16 entries.

Comment: I modified this code a bit instead of using the ‘-eq’ operator I used match. Because the full name of each program to look for can be shortened this way. Also, I removed the foreach and instead used many if statements. Again, I am testing for values for 16 different programs and exporting the results to a csv. so the extra code is worth it so there’s no repetition. I also piped the displayversion as well and it all worked like a charm. Thanks for the help, piping the values is what solved my problem.